# Lucene sorting chinese characters by strokes/radicals

Tags: lucene

Anyone know if Lucene's sort by field feature will sort chinese characters by strokes/radicals, or if there's a way to enable it do so? I couldn't find any relevant answer in their docs.

Comment: I don't think there are other options except "Unicode binary order".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-collation/index.html, which describes how to use Collator order.

Comment: Sorry, this looks interesting, but I'm not sure how to apply it to the sorting? The Sort class only allows me to specify the fields to be sorted by, but not any collator or collationkeyfilter? (Sorry, kind of new to Lucene)

Comment: The package summary has some examples: http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-collation/org/apache/lucene/collation/package-summary.html